# How to create this Hierarchy

Tags: t-sql, hierarchy

I have 3 tables: structures, account range and accountvalueUSD. From the hierarchy of parent and child ID in table structure, I want to create a hierarchy like this :

```
Level 1...Level 2...Level 3...Level 4....account...valueusd
111       112   113     114     100     1000
111     112     113     114     101     2000
```

The table structure links with table account range with key: financialitem

The table acountrange links with table account value with key: accountfrom and accountto with accountnumber

Can you please help me how to do it?

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[structure](
    [Financialitem] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [ChildID] [int] NULL,
    [NextID] [int] NULL,
    [Level] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT INTO [dbo].[structure]
VALUES
(111,1,null,2,null,1),
(112,2,1,3,null,2),
(113,3,2,4,null,3),
(114,4,3,null,null,4),
(221,5,2,6,null,3),
(222,6,5,null,7,4),
(223,7,5,null,null,4)

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[accountrange](
    [Financialitem] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [Accountfrom] [int] NULL,
    [Accountto] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT INTO [dbo].[accountrange]
VALUES
(114,100,105),
(222,200,205),
(223,300,305)


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[accountvalue](
    [accountnumber] [int] NULL,
    [valuesUSD] [int]  NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT INTO [dbo].[accountvalue]
VALUES
(100,1000),
(101,2000),
(301,1500),
(201,1400)
```

Comment: Can you indicate what system language or notation you are using or asking about please.

Comment: Thanks Brian, i am using T SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data you provided, this query gives the output you specified. It's hard coded to 4 levels, so if you needed something more dynamic, then further thought would be required.

I've also assumed that the reason the 221 branch didn't appear is because it needs to match on both parent and child ID columns.

```
select L1.Financialitem as [Level 1]
     , L2.Financialitem as [Level 2]
     , L3.Financialitem as [Level 3]
     , ar.Financialitem as [Level 4]
     , av.accountnumber, av.valuesUSD
from accountrange ar
inner join accountvalue av on av.accountnumber between ar.Accountfrom and ar.Accountto
inner join structure as L4 on L4.Financialitem = ar.Financialitem
inner join structure as L3 on L3.ID = L4.ParentID and L3.ChildID = L4.ID
inner join structure as L2 on L2.ID = L3.ParentID and L2.ChildID = L3.ID
inner join structure as L1 on L1.ID = L2.ParentID and L1.ChildID = L2.ID
```